# Lost Your password Hook Not Showing Up

Tags: functions, password

This code used to work fine but after updating Wordpress, it doesn't seem to work anymore. I am not getting my custom link to appear. Any ideas?

```
function hook_lost_your_password ( $text ) {
        if ($text == 'Lost your password?'){
            $text .= '<br /><a href="/invitation/" class="neolog">Not a member? <span>Request an invitation.</span></a>';
        }
    return $text;
}
add_filter( 'gettext', 'hook_lost_your_password' );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `wp_lostpassword_url`, or you can directly `echo` it wherever it's required just by

```
<br />
<a href= "<?php echo wp_lostpassword_url(); ?>" class="neolog"><?php _e('Not a member?','text-domain'); ?> <span><?php _e('Request an invitation.','text-domain'); ?></span></a>
```

You can visit [WordPress Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_lostpassword_url) for more info.